# string length in java

Tags: java, android

```
String h;
h=(String) Tok.nextElement();
System.out.println("" + ++n +": "+h);
h.trim();   
System.out.println("The length of h :"+n+h.length());
wordlist[now]=h;
System.out.println("Now length is"+wordlist[now].length());
```

This "\u0B9A\u0BBF\u0BAF\u0BA9" is the string assigned to h.The output is

> The length of h :128
>
> Now length is 41

I'm totally confused :( help please. Sorry . the pblm is not with operator but with length also note that the length of h is 128 !! where as the actual length is 28

Comment: You should formulate a question here ... what do you expect? What do you get? What's the point of this code?

Comment: Sorry marza.I need the length of the string ie i expect both print statements to display 28 .but m not getting it :(

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Remember: a good question gets good answers. Bad questions don't.

Comment: Well, @Rudy, above, has the answer to your question .. I was about to write the same exact thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the problem of your String concat.

```
System.out.println("The length of h :"+n+h.length());
```

The h's length is really 28. However You put var **"n"** before that, where I believe the value of n was 1.

Since you concat it with String, instead of sum n and h, it will **just concat n and h as String**.

So n+h.length = "1"+"28" = "128"

In other words, please change your syntax to :

`System.out.println("The length of h :"+h.length());`

I also want to comment this syntax:

```
h.trim();
```

What is the purpose of having this syntax? If you want to trim variable h, you should assign it back to var h .

```
h=h.trim();
```

Comment: Also, the variable `now` is not defined in this block, so what's the point of using the `n` variable if you then put it in an array using `now` as index?

Answer (score 5):

`wordlist[now++]=h` assigns `h` to `wordlist[now]`, *then* increases `now`, after which `wordlist[now]` is most likely *not* `h` (unless is already was before).

You may want to use `wordlist[++now]=h` instead. Better yet, avoid using incrementors within statements altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy stems from where/how you use the `now++` statement.

First, you're getting the length of the string located at `wordlist[now]` (pre-increment) and in the subsequent statement, you're getting the length of the string at `wordlist[now+1]` (post-increment).